# How to apply AspectJ to all projects in workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, aop, aspectj

Good day developers.

Please help me. I have aspectj project where I have my aspect class. How can I apply this aspect to all projects in my workspace. Like I ahve Project1 and class inside with mainn thread and method execute in main thread. I need my aspect for for this class in defferent project of workspace.
Is it possible???

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click a project in Eclipse, select "configure build path" and go to the "projects"-tab. There you can add any of the other projects in Eclipse to the current project's build path, which makes it available there. Add your aspect-project to whichever one that needs it.

Also (you probably know this already) right click your project and select "configure"-> convert to AspectJ-project to add the aspectj-jars to the libraries.